# Classes do autoload composer não funcionam

Tags: php, composer, php-autoload

Estou utilizando o `composer` para gerenciar as classes do meu projeto, no arquivo `composer.json` defini as pastas, nas classes coloquei os seus respectivos `namespaces`, porém não consigo usa-las em outros arquivos.

Estrutura de pastas

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Autoload

```
{
    "require": {
        "sendgrid/sendgrid": "^5.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Classes\\" : "Classes",
            "DAO\\" : "DAO"
        }
    }
}
```

Classe

```
namespace Classes;

    class UsuarioLinkedin { }
}
```

Utilizando a classe

```
<?php 
    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
    use Classes\UsuarioLinkedin;
    $usuarioLink = new UsuarioLinkedin();
```

Erro

> `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Classes\UsuarioLinkedin' not found in C:\wamp64\www\ibico-solution\form\formLogin.php on line 58`

Comment: já deu o comando `php composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: Sim rodei, o retorno foi esse Generated autoload files containing 0 classes

Comment: Tem alguma configuração faltando ou algo que você não esteja dizendo, aonde está a pasta `vendor` ?

Comment: Desculpa acabei cortando a pasta vendor do print, mas ela está no mesmo nível da pastas mostradas na imagem

Comment: mude o seu psr-4 assim: `"psr-4": {
            "Classes\\" : "Classes/",
            "DAO\\" : "DAO/"
        }`

Comment: alterei mas não funcionou

Comment: Acabei de simular o exemplo e no meu deu certo... claro eu não estou vendo o seu código por completo, mas, tem algum erro na programação.

Comment: Estranho arquivo que vc usando as classes estão no mesmo nível das outras pastas ? Ou esta dentro de alguma delas ?

Comment: eu estou usando o meu exemplo no mesmo nível, não muda muito se você passar o caminho corretamente, talvez seja isso o seu problema

Comment: Desculpa caminho de qual arquivo?

Comment: `C:\wamp64\www\ibico-solution\form\formLogin.php on line 58` esse não sei se isso ta certo o caminho do arquivo, como foi configurado, ou seja, o seu erro é local de difícil reprodução.